# Empty String Input Validation

Tags: c#, validation, c#-4.0, console-application

I've been having trouble on understanding as of why my custom empty string validation method does not work compared when I check for an empty string directly

```
Validation.EmptyValidation(title,
"Please, do not leave the course title field empty!" +
"\r\nEnter the course title: ");
```

It does not output the course title in the end, but when I do it this way it does:

```
while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
{
   Console.WriteLine("No empty string: ");
   title = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Class:

```
 Console.WriteLine("* Create Course *\r\n");

 Console.WriteLine("Enter the course title: ");
 string title = Console.ReadLine();

 while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
 {
    Console.WriteLine("No empty string: ");
    title = Console.ReadLine();
 }

 Validation.EmptyValidation(title,
 "Please, do not leave the course title field empty!" +
 "\r\nEnter the course title: ");

 Console.WriteLine("\r\nEnter the course description: ");
 string description = Console.ReadLine();
 Validation.EmptyValidation(description,
 "Please, do not leave the course description field empty!" +
 "\r\nEnter the course description: ");

 Console.WriteLine("\r\nEnter the number of students in the course: ");
 =string studentsInput = Console.ReadLine();
 int.TryParse(studentsInput, out int students);

 CreateCourse(currentCourse, title, description, students);

 public static Course CreateCourse (Course _currentCourse, string title string description, int students)
    {
        Course course = new Course(title, description, students);
        _currentCourse = course;
        _currentCourse.Title = course.Title;

        Console.WriteLine($"\r\nThank you for registering the {_currentCourse.Title} course.\r\n" +
          $"\r\nCourse Information" +
          $"\r\nTitle: {_currentCourse.Title}" +
          $"\r\nDescription: {_currentCourse.Description}" +
          $"\r\nStudents: {_currentCourse.Capacity}");

        return _currentCourse;
    }
```

Empty Validation Method:

```
    public static string EmptyValidation(string input, string prompt)
    {
        while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(prompt);
            input = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        return input;
    }
```

Comment: *"why my custom empty string validation method does not work"*... How could we possibly know if we cant see the code for `Validation.EmptyValidation` ?

Comment: Eh... where is the implementation for the Validation?

Comment: I forgot to add it, my bad. It's the last piece of code.

Comment: You start the `Validation.EmptyValidation`, but you ignore the return value.

Comment: I would suggest to use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` otherwise the user can input `"        "`  (several spaces or tabs) and this would be valid in the current situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a couple of things going wrong here

```
// you weren't returning the results 
title = Validation.EmptyValidation(title,
"Please, do not leave the course title field empty!" +
"\r\nEnter the course title: ");
```

Also if you don't need the other validation anymore you are best to remove it

```
//while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
//{
//    Console.WriteLine("No empty string: ");
//    title = Console.ReadLine();
// }
```